# Const array of const strings and ERROR "not a compile-time constant"

Tags: c, string, pointers, constants

I want to make modular, enumerated matrix of const strings.

I have made two typedefs

`globals.h`

```
   #define PAGES_COUNT              8
   #define PARAMETERS_COUNT     8

   typedef const char* const rom_string;
   typedef rom_string const* const rom_string_array;
```

`pages.h`

```
    #include "globals.h"

    typedef enum page_enum{
        PAGE_1_ENUM,
        PAGE_2_ENUM,
    }page_enum;

    extern rom_string pages_names[PAGES_COUNT];
    extern rom_string_array page_list[PAGES_COUNT];
```

`pages.c`

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "pages.h"
#include "page_1.h"
#include "page_2.h"

    rom_string pages_names[PAGES_COUNT] = {
        [PAGE_1_ENUM]   = page_1_name,
        [PAGE_2_ENUM]   = page_2_name,
    };

    rom_string_array page_list[PAGES_COUNT] = {
        [PAGE_1_ENUM]   = page_1,
        [PAGE_2_ENUM]   = page_2,
};
```

`page_1.h`

```
    typedef enum page_1_params{
        PAGE_1_PARAMETER_A,
        PAGE_1_PARAMETER_B,
        PAGE_1_PARAMETER_C,
        PAGE_1_PARAMETER_D,
        PAGE_1_PARAMS_END,
    }page_1_params;

    #define PAGE_1_PARAMS_COUNT (PAGE_1_PARAMS_END)

    extern rom_string       page_1_name;
    extern rom_string_array page_1[PARAMETERS_COUNT];
```

`page_1.c`

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "page_1.h"

    rom_string  page_1_name = "page1.";

    rom_string_array page_1[PARAMETERS_COUNT] = {
        [PAGE_1_PARAMETER_A]    = "text1",
        [PAGE_1_PARAMETER_B]    = "text2",
        [PAGE_1_PARAMETER_C]    = "text3",
        [PAGE_1_PARAMETER_D]    = "text4",
        [PAGE_1_PARAMS_END]     = "",
    };
```

`page_2.h`

```
#include "globals.h"

    typedef enum page_2_params{
        PAGE_2_PARAMETER_A,
        PAGE_2_PARAMETER_B,
        PAGE_2_PARAMETER_C,
        PAGE_2_PARAMETER_D,
        PAGE_2_PARAMS_END,
    }page_2_params;

    #define PAGE_2_PARAMS_COUNT (PAGE_2_PARAMS_END)

    extern rom_string       page_2_name;
    extern rom_string_array page_2[PARAMETERS_COUNT];
```

`page_2.c`

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "page_2.h"

    rom_string  page_2_name = "page2.";

    rom_string_array page_2[PARAMETERS_COUNT] = {
        [PAGE_2_PARAMETER_A]    = "text5",
        [PAGE_2_PARAMETER_B]    = "text6",
        [PAGE_2_PARAMETER_C]    = "text7",
        [PAGE_2_PARAMETER_D]    = "text8",
        [PAGE_2_PARAMS_END]     = "",
    };
```

Problem 1: the `warning`
I have tried "small" prototype in online C compiler and have no warnings, but on my main "XC8" i've got a next warning message, one for the each parameter of each array:

```
incompatible pointer types initializing 'rom_string_array' (aka 'const char *const *const') with an expression of type 'rom_string_array [8]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

[8] here is from array size macro .
It differs for different arrays.

Problem 2: the `error`

```
error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

This error occurs for the element:

```
[PAGE_1_ENUM]   = page_1_name,
```

of `pages_names` array. If im deleting this element, error occurs on the next one. 
With a `page_list` ive have same situation.
Its not sensible for me, i think this is a linker job.
So what i must do, include ALL in one file? 
Can i some how get around this?

Reworked upon request.

Comment: I'm sure these errors have line numbers.

Comment: One error for first element of first array. If i delete it, then error occurs on the next.

Comment: `ui_page_service_name` is apparently not a compile time constant, but you have not included its definition, so how can we tell?

Comment: ... and `const` variables don't count.

Comment: I don't wanted to include the text of all files, cause it the same. One second i make this

Comment: It doesn't necessary have to be everything.  It needs to be enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyway, `service_page` done =)

Comment: Just make a small program that gives you the same error. It's probably due to you putting the values of variables in global arrays.

Comment: Regarding your Problem 1: an array is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable like this with `rom_string_array`:

```
rom_string_array my_array[SIZE];
```

It is the same as:

```
rom_string const* const my_array[SIZE];
```

Which is the same as:

```
const char* const const* const my_array[SIZE];
```

So what you're declaring (ignoring the `const` quantifiers for now) is not an array of `char *` but an array of `char **`.  You should do away with `rom_string_array` entirely and create your arrays like this:

```
rom_string my_array[SIZE];
```

Regarding the "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" error, variables defined at file scope may only be initialized, as the error message says, with a compile time constant.   This includeds numeric constants, string constants, and simple expressions involving those, as well as preprocessor macros that expand to one of these.  It does **not** include other variables even if they are declared `const`.

So you'll need to change `page_2_name` to a macro to allow it to be used as an initializer, i.e.:

```
#define page_2_name "page1."
```

Comment: My hero. It works. The biggest thanks! I changed `rom_string_array page_2[PARAMETERS_COUNT]` to `rom_string page_2[PARAMETERS_COUNT]` and warnings has gone. Same with ` page_2_name`, i changed it to `#define PAGE_2_NAME` and error has gone.

Comment: Can i request one more explanation. If initializing with "other" variables is restricted, why initializing with string array pointers is still allowed? I mean `page_list` array.